# apache storm/spark and data visualisation tool(s)

Tags: data-visualization, apache-storm

I have been searching for hours bu i did not find a clear answer. I would like to know what it is the most suitable data visualization tool(s) to use with apache storm/spark. I know there is tableau and jaspersoft but they are not free. Furthermore, there is the possibility of elasticsearch and kibana but I would like to find/try something else. So, do you have an idea please ?!

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your use case a bit? Is it for reporting? Realtime graphs of data?

Comment: The purpose is to get streaming data and therefore to do realtime graphs of data

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving much info here. Storm is stream processing engine, Spark can do a lot more but in both cases you need to deposit information somewhere. If it is text based data, you may do Solr+Graphana or Elastic+Kibana. If it is SQL or NoSQL DB there are many tools mostly around data base type. There are BIs for time series with InfluxDB, etc. With Spark, you have Zepplin that can do some level of BI. The last is to have your own visualization but I would be careful with D3 as it is not very good for dynamic charts. You may be better with pure JS charts like HighCharts, etc.

Best of luck.

Comment: I will use a NoSQL database such as cassandra or elasticsearch. However, what is the need to use spark with elasticsearch while I can use Logstash. That's why i was looking for something different from ELK.

Comment: Cassandra has build in support for Solr and Spark so you may not need to use multiple systems. Elasticsearch is not a DB, it is a reverse indexing service. I am not clear on why you need Logstash, unless you plan to use it to grok data to Elastic

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Zeppelin](http://zeppelin.apache.org/) is a great web based front end for Spark

[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) is an excellent chart library.

[spark-highcharts](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts) add easy modeling feature from Spark DataFrame to highcharts. It can be used in Zeppelin, spark-shell, or other spark application.

spark-highcharts can generate self contain HTML page with full interaction feature. It can share to other users.

Using following docker command try out

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -d knockdata/zeppelin-highcharts
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `D3 Javascript library`.It provides a very good Visualization library

```
https://d3js.org/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that way I have to code myself the dashboard what i am tryig to avoid

Comment: Yes you have to code the dahsbaord, alternatively you can also look out for Apache Zeppelin. http://zeppelin-project.org/