# Apache Spark and Cassandra Visualization tool

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, data-visualization

I am working on analytic application using Apache Spark and Cassandra to store and analyze data.

I'd like to visualize that data.

Is there any visualization tool like kibana and Grafana that can be used with Apache Spark and Cassandra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes.

Kibana can be used Along with Spark/Casandra : Example [here](http://Using%20ELK%20(elasticsearch%20+%20logstash%20+%20kibana)%20to%20aggregate%20cassandra%20and%20spark%20logs)

- Below combination is also possible.

Spark + Casandra + Solr+Graphana 
or
 Spark + Casandra +  Elastic+ Kibana

#### Since Casandra is no sql database(same is true for hbase as well) and you need to index through Solr or ES to use Kibana or Graphana.

- Zeppelin also good choice for visualization
- [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) is another option you can consider.

Also have a look at 
1) https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts
2) [apache storm/spark and data visualisation tool(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37346477/647053)

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

Comment: But Zeppelin is a notebook, Yes it helps in visualizing Apache Spark data. But we cannot provide that notebook visualization to client. The issue with kibana and grafana is that they dn't provide security of data, and they dn't have visualization for self service filters for run time analytics.

Comment: @Arslan, spark-highcharts has a html function which will generate self contain HTML with interaction function. It can send directly the html file to clients.

Comment: @Rockie Yang, but the html file data will be static and user is able to update the size.